# application monotone class theorem

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to prove the following

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra    and let $\mathbb{P}_1,\mathbb{P}_2$ be two probability measures on $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$. Assume that $\mathbb{P}_1,\mathbb{P}_2$ coincide on a monotone class containing $\mathcal{A}$. Prove that $\mathbb{P}_1$ and $\mathbb{P}_2$ coincide on $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

*proof:* Let 
$$
\mathcal{D}=\{A \in \sigma(\mathcal{A}): \mathbb{P}_1(A)=\mathbb{P}_2(A)\}.
$$
By definition, the algebra $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{D}$. If I show that $\mathcal{D}$ is a monotone class, then $\mathcal{D}=\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ by the monotone class theorem. Is this reasoning correct?

Let $(E_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{D}$ and $(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N} } \subset \mathcal{D}$ be a monotone increasing and decreasing sequence respectively.  Set  $A_n=E_n\setminus E_{n-1}$, so $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is disjoint and $\bigcup_n A_n= \bigcup_n E_n$. Thus, 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}_1\left(\bigcup_n E_n \right)&= \mathbb{P}_1 \left( \bigcup_n A_n \right)= \sum_{n}\mathbb{P}_1(A_n) & \textrm{ countably additivity of } \mathbb{P}_1\\
&=\sum_{n}\mathbb{P}_2(A_n) & \textrm{ assumption } \\
&=\mathbb{P}_2\left(\bigcup_n A_n\right )= \mathbb{P}_2\left(\bigcup_n E_n \right) & \textrm{countably additivity of }\mathbb{P}_2
\end{align*}
Thus, $\bigcup_n E_n \in \mathcal{D}$. Same reasoning proves that $\bigcap_n F_n \in \mathcal{D}$. Therefore, by Monotone Class Theorem, it follows that $\mathbb{P}_1$ and $\mathbb{P}_2$ coincide on $\mathcal{D}=\sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I just wrote out my attempt.